# Select first 4 rows of a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I select the first 4 rows of a `data.frame`:

```
              Weight Response
1   Control     59      0.0
2 Treatment     90      0.8
3 Treatment     47      0.1
4 Treamment    106      0.1
5   Control     85      0.7
6 Treatment     73      0.6
7   Control     61      0.2
```

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Use `head`:

```
dnow <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=runif(100))
head(dnow,4) ## default is 6
```

Comment: Hello, what if you want to get the rows 5 to 7?

Comment: You can use the "index" answer pointed out elsewhere. In this situation I normally use the slice function in dplyr. (Behavior depends on the grouping.)

Answer (score 154):

Using the index:

```
df[1:4,]
```

Where the values in the parentheses can be interpreted as either logical, numeric, or character (matching the respective names):

```
df[row.index, column.index]
```

Read help(`[`) for more detail on this subject, and also read about [index matrices](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-matrices) in the Introduction to R.

Comment: This also works if you want the first four rows from just one column. To get the first four response values: `df[1:4, "Response"]`.

Answer (score 31):

In case someone is interested in `dplyr` solution, it's very intuitive:

```
dt <- dt %>%
  slice(1:4)
```

Answer (score 14):

If you have less than 4 rows, you can use the `head` function ( `head(data, 4)` or `head(data, n=4)`) and it works like a charm. But, assume we have the following dataset with 15 rows

```
>data <- data <- read.csv("./data.csv", sep = ";", header=TRUE)

>data
 LungCap Age Height Smoke Gender Caesarean
1    6.475   6   62.1    no   male        no
2   10.125  18   74.7   yes female        no
3    9.550  16   69.7    no female       yes
4   11.125  14   71.0    no   male        no
5    4.800   5   56.9    no   male        no
6    6.225  11   58.7    no female        no
7    4.950   8   63.3    no   male       yes
8    7.325  11   70.4    no  male         no
9    8.875  15   70.5    no   male        no
10   6.800  11   59.2    no   male        no
11   6.900  12   59.3    no   male        no
12   6.100  13   59.4    no   male        no
13   6.110  14   59.5    no   male        no
14   6.120  15   59.6    no   male        no
15   6.130  16   59.7    no   male        no
```

Let's say, you want to select the first 10 rows. The easiest way to do it would be `data[1:10, ]`.

```
> data[1:10,]
   LungCap Age Height Smoke Gender Caesarean
1    6.475   6   62.1    no   male        no
2   10.125  18   74.7   yes female        no
3    9.550  16   69.7    no female       yes
4   11.125  14   71.0    no   male        no
5    4.800   5   56.9    no   male        no
6    6.225  11   58.7    no female        no
7    4.950   8   63.3    no   male       yes
8    7.325  11   70.4    no  male         no
9    8.875  15   70.5    no   male        no
10   6.800  11   59.2    no   male        no
```

However, let's say you try to retrieve the first 19 rows and see the what happens - you will have missing values

```
> data[1:19,]
     LungCap Age Height Smoke Gender Caesarean
1      6.475   6   62.1    no   male        no
2     10.125  18   74.7   yes female        no
3      9.550  16   69.7    no female       yes
4     11.125  14   71.0    no   male        no
5      4.800   5   56.9    no   male        no
6      6.225  11   58.7    no female        no
7      4.950   8   63.3    no   male       yes
8      7.325  11   70.4    no  male         no
9      8.875  15   70.5    no   male        no
10     6.800  11   59.2    no   male        no
11     6.900  12   59.3    no   male        no
12     6.100  13   59.4    no   male        no
13     6.110  14   59.5    no   male        no
14     6.120  15   59.6    no   male        no
15     6.130  16   59.7    no   male        no
NA        NA  NA     NA  <NA>   <NA>      <NA>
NA.1      NA  NA     NA  <NA>   <NA>      <NA>
NA.2      NA  NA     NA  <NA>   <NA>      <NA>
NA.3      NA  NA     NA  <NA>   <NA>      <NA>
```

and with the head() function,

```
> head(data, 19) # or head(data, n=19)
   LungCap Age Height Smoke Gender Caesarean
1    6.475   6   62.1    no   male        no
2   10.125  18   74.7   yes female        no
3    9.550  16   69.7    no female       yes
4   11.125  14   71.0    no   male        no
5    4.800   5   56.9    no   male        no
6    6.225  11   58.7    no female        no
7    4.950   8   63.3    no   male       yes
8    7.325  11   70.4    no  male         no
9    8.875  15   70.5    no   male        no
10   6.800  11   59.2    no   male        no
11   6.900  12   59.3    no   male        no
12   6.100  13   59.4    no   male        no
13   6.110  14   59.5    no   male        no
14   6.120  15   59.6    no   male        no
15   6.130  16   59.7    no   male        no
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 12):

For at DataFrame one can simply type

```
head(data, num=10L)
```

to get the first 10 for example.

For a data.frame one can simply type

```
head(data, 10)
```

to get the first 10.

Comment: How is this answer different from the accepted answer which was posted 5 years ago before this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2667843 Does it add any new information?

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `slice_head` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  slice_head(n = 4)
#>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Please note:** `n` must be explicitly named!